# can you fix this?

Tags: tables

Can you fix this? There are several horrors!

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | }
 \hline                 
   Modelo & Gl & SC & F \\
\hline
\beta'=(\beta_0,\beta_1) & 2   & \beta'X'Y  & $\frac{(SSE_r-SSEc)/(k-g)}{SSE_c/(n-[k+1])}$\\
Residual                 & n-2 & Y'Y-\beta'X'Y & \\
 \hline  
 Total & n & \textbf{Y'Y} & asd\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format- at the moment it doesn't quite fit :)

Answer (score 5):

`\beta` can be used only in mathmode. Here is a way of coding – but I'm unsure of what is supposed to be maths formulae, what is supposed  to be text. I use the `cellspace` package to have a minimal distance between the top of the contents of a cell and the line above, and similarly between the bottom of the contents and the line below:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools, array, bm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\SSE}{SSE}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\cellspacetoplimit=4pt
\cellspacebottomlimit=4pt

\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

   \[ \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
   \begin{array}{ | *{4}{Sc|}}
      \hline
      \text{Modelo} & Gl & SC & F \\
      \hline
      \beta'=(\beta_0,\beta_1) & 2   &  \beta'X'Y  &
      \dfrac{(\SSE_r-\SSE_c)/(k-g)}{\SSE_c/(n-[k+1])}\\
      \text{Residual} & n-2 & Y'Y-\beta'X'Y   &  \\
      \hline
      \text{Total} & n  &  \bm{Y'Y} & \text{asd}\\
      \hline
   \end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Envoke `\DeclareMathOperator*{\SSE}{SSe}` and then use `\SSE`. Also, `\text{Residual }` should be `\text{Residual}`.

Comment: Btw. I guess that `Gl` and `SC` are also operators.

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg: Thanks. Fixed it, and corrected \SSE c to \SSE_c (seems  to be a typo).

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg: Do you think so? That doesn't seem very consistent with the labelling of the row.

Comment: Hmmm. That's a good point. `:)`